# Google Maps fitBounds is not working properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, fitbounds

I have a problem with googlemaps fitBounds functions.

```
for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
 var country = countries[i];
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(country.lat), parseFloat(country.lng));
 mapBounds.extend(latlng); 
}

map.fitBounds(mapBounds);
```

Some icons will be displayed outside the viewport / Visible area.

And idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

Consider the following example, which will generate 10 random points on  the North East USA, and applies the `fitBounds()` method.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps LatLngBounds.extend() Demo</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
           type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
   });

   var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

   var randomPoint, i;

   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     // Generate 10 random points within North East USA
     randomPoint = new google.maps.LatLng( 39.00 + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 20, 
                                          -77.00 + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

     // Draw a marker for each random point
     new google.maps.Marker({
       position: randomPoint, 
       map: map
     });

     // Extend markerBounds with each random point.
     markerBounds.extend(randomPoint);
   }

   // At the end markerBounds will be the smallest bounding box to contain
   // our 10 random points

   // Finally we can call the Map.fitBounds() method to set the map to fit
   // our markerBounds
   map.fitBounds(markerBounds);

   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Refreshing this example many times, no marker ever goes outside the viewport. At most, sometimes a marker is slightly clipped from the top when hidden behind the controls:

[image: Google Maps LatLngBounds.extend() Demo]

It is also worth nothing that the `fitBounds()` always leaves a small margin between the `LatLngBounds` object and the viewport. This is clearly shown in the screenshots below, where the red bounding box represents the `LatLngBounds` which is passed to the `fitBounds()` method:

[image: fitBounds Padding]

[image: fitBounds Padding]

You may also be interested in checking out the following Stack Overflow posts on the topic:

- [fitbounds() in Google maps api V3 does not fit bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494756/fitbounds-in-google-maps-api-v3-does-not-fit-bounds)
- [Google Maps v3 - Automating Zoom Level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245564/google-maps-javascript-api-automate-zoom-level)

Answer (score 0):

Show us a link to the patient. How many countries do you have in the countries array? The entire world? Are your bounds crossing the anti-meridian?

country.lat and country.lng are one point per country, and that's not enough to define the bounding box of the country. Is that some sort of "country centroid"?

If that's the case, and if you have markers east of the centroid of the easternmost country, or to the west of the centroid of the westermost country, those markers will, of course, fall outside the bounds that you're defining.

The `map.fitBounds()` method works fine. :-)

Marcelo.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your google map object is shown properly in the area you have given.
it is possible that some part of your google map object is overflowed outside it's container and the markers are in that area, which they exists by you can't see them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the result of fitBounds() is depending on the minZoom value.

For my use-case I managed to recenter the view to cover all the markers by using: map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
`

```
zoomToAllMarkers() {
    if (!this.mapMarkers.length) {
        return;
    }
    let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.mapMarkers.length; i++) {
        bounds.extend(this.mapMarkers[i].getPosition());
    }
    this.map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
}
```

`