# Google Maps Android zoom to country

Tags: java, android, maps

I need the following implementation in Android: 
 [How to get Google Maps API to set the correct zoom level for a country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265055/how-to-get-google-maps-api-to-set-the-correct-zoom-level-for-a-country)

For those that do'nt want to click: 

**How to zoom to a country by name in an Android application?**

Anyone got a pointer on how to accomplish this task?

Edit: i guess i can parse this [file](http://www.nearby.org.uk/coords/countries.csv). 
But then the question is: `map.fitBounds()` kind of method in Android?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok ill answer my own question. I parsed the [file](http://www.nearby.org.uk/coords/countries.csv) above and used the following code to zoom to the countries:

```
MapController controller = mapView.getController();
controller.zoomToSpan(
        (maxLat - minLat),
        (maxLong - minLong));

controller.animateTo(new GeoPoint(
            (maxLat + minLat)/2,                 
            (maxLong + minLong)/2 ));
```

Comment: What is MapController?