# jquery goMap plugin and google maps api V3 fitBounds to a country

Tags: google-maps, jquery-plugins, google-maps-api-3

I am using [goMap jQuery plugin](http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/) for integrating Google Maps api v3. I have some external controls overlapped on the map - list of countries and I would like to fit bounds off a map to a clicked country.

goMap has fitBounds function but it only fits to the bounds of markers on the map. I found another question and answer regarding how to fit bounds of a map to a country with Google maps api v2 and v3 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265055/how-to-get-google-maps-api-to-set-the-correct-zoom-level-for-a-country), but I don't know how to combine this with goMap plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used goMap, but it appears you can access the Google Maps API Map object with `$.goMap.map`. You can then use the Google API `fitBounds` (or whatever) function directly. Again, I'm not sure one way or the other if there would be any bad side-effects related to the state of the goMap object.

Comment: Hey I will accept your answer. It did help me solve my problem by using $.goMap.map!