# Bounds value for Brazil in google place API for autocomplete beahaviour

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using google Place API for autocomplete behaviour in android.

```
PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results = Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),mBounds, null);
```

I just want to ask what would be the `mBounds` value here so it should biased towards a Brazil.

I have the LatLng bounds value for sydney.

```
private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_GREATER_SYDNEY = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(-34.041458, 150.790100), new LatLng(-33.682247, 151.383362));
```

But, I'm not able to find bounds value for Brazil.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I couldn't find out the exact bounds anywhere online, so maybe you could use the Google Maps client-side geocoder to get the bounding box as explained in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2265459/4241842) answer.

Comment: Ok Thanks, let me do that.