# How to adjust Google Maps viewport to a country size? (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I'm using the places API with Google Maps. I want that whenever I pick a country I am able to adjust the viewport to the size of the country.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

On the PlacesApi I can't get any information related to it (I guess)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Google Maps API to set the correct zoom level for a country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265055/how-to-get-google-maps-api-to-set-the-correct-zoom-level-for-a-country)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick Google search and stumbled upon [this stackoverflow answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265055/how-to-get-google-maps-api-to-set-the-correct-zoom-level-for-a-country)

It seems to answer your questions.