# Custom zoom level on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have a simple map with zoom level 4 at this point. Zoom level 5 is too big for me. Ideally, I'd like 4.6 zoom level which is possible in iOS SDK for Google maps.

Is there a way on how I can set the zoom level to 4.6? I want the map to occupy full page, so cannot really put in a div and use that part of it.

The objective is to show full USA in the center.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Map example</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      var layer;
       var layer1;
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: {lat: 39.8282, lng: -98.5795}
        });


      }
    </script> 
    <script async defer src=
    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBMtoh9P3UkoxbXndKu_HOP7KsVwTRvxGU&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: see this links,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265055/how-to-get-google-maps-api-to-set-the-correct-zoom-level-for-a-country
  
  and,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048975/google-maps-v3-how-to-calculate-the-zoom-level-for-a-given-bounds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use CSS zoom to make your map fits your need.
For example, set Google map zoom to 4, then set #map zoom to 1.15 (because you want Google map zoom to 4.6 = 1.15 * 4)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Map example</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
        zoom: 1.15;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: {lat: 39.8282, lng: -98.5795}
        });


      }
    </script> 
    <script async defer src=
    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBMtoh9P3UkoxbXndKu_HOP7KsVwTRvxGU&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Zoom levels on Google Maps are integers. Full stop.  Your only option is to change the size of the div that contains the google.maps.Map object.

Comment: You are using a percent size for your map currently, that won't work with this option.  The specific settings will depend on the size of the display.