# How to set zoom default level in google maps

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Found this Free webiste online that i want to customize but i cant change the default zoom lvl, i dont know javascript. I would like to know what lines of code i need to add in order to change the zoom lvl.
Thanks, :=),
also i dont know if i have to include other code/info here, just tell me if you need more info.

```
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <!-- Container -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

            </div>
        </div><!-- Container end -->
    </footer><!-- Footer end -->


    <!-- scroll up-->
    <div class="scrollup">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
    </div><!-- End off scroll up->

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>     
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootsnav js -->
    <script src="js/bootsnav.js"></script>

    <!-- JS Implementing Plugins -->
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script src="js/gmaps.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            map = new GMaps({
                el: '#ourmaps',
                lat: 15, 
                lng: 15,
                scrollwheel: true

            });

            //locations request
            map.getElevations({
                locations: [[15, 15]],
                callback: function (result, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
                        for (var i in result) {
                            map.addMarker({
                                lat: result[i].location.lat(),
                                lng: result[i].location.lng(),
                                infoWindow: {
                                    content: '<address class="tooltip_address"><b>aaaa</b><br />aaa<br />aaaa<br />aaaa <br /></address>'
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    </script>


    <!--main js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom zoom level on Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044363/custom-zoom-level-on-google-maps)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`zoom: 8`

From [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#zoom-levels).
see [This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#MapOptions) also

Answer (score 0):

you're using Gmaps.js so you will need to find documentation about this javascript, as the webpage says you need to use `setZoom` that allows an integer of your desired zoom, also you will need to use `setCenter` to center the map on your desired marker.

Here's the GMaps.js website: [GMaps.js](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/)

Here's where you cand find all the parameters that allows:
[Documentation](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/documentation.html#GMaps-setZoom)

You can also set the zoom when you create your Gmaps, so this is the main code you need to edit in your example:

```
map = new GMaps({
       el: '#ourmaps',
       lat: 15, 
       lng: 15,
       scrollwheel: true,
       zoom: 15 //Your desired zoom
            });
```

Also I find a note on a blog that if you use more than 1 marker you may be using::

```
map.setZoom((map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds))); //To rezoom the map
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter()); //To center the map
```

[Reference about using more than one marker](https://www.alunr.com/gmap-mapsetzoom/)

Hope my answer helps you!!